# Strange whitespace can't get rid of HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I've inserted buttons into the cells of.  However, try as I might, I can't get rid of some whitespace that shows up between the top of the cell and the button.

Here's an example in Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Bz36/1/

Where I have a simple table with a button

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
             <button id="1"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with some css and attempts to get rid of it:

```
button {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr td {
    height: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
```

Can anyone figure out how to get rid of it?  Thanks!

Comment: Turns out I'm al idiot and should retire to my bed.  I would anser my own question but can't.  The line-spacing needed to be set: `line-height: 0px'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using any text value for the button, use `font-size: 0;` or `line-height: 0;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bz36/12/) (Font Size 0)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bz36/13/) (Line Height 0)

Also `id="1"` is invalid, id name cannot be started with an int

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
button {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display: block;
}

table, td, button {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;    
}
```

This will set `margins` and `paddings` of all the elements involved to `0px;` and set the `button` element to `display: block;` to get rid of some inline element white-space.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bz36/14/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the problem is via your jsfiddle.

Also, `none` is not a valid property of `white-space` in your CSS. Do you know what your doing, or are you just adding random styling hoping that it will work?

Anyway, your code is not properly formatted, the CSS ends in `</table>`, what? Also, your html is not constructed properly here, nor in the jsfiddle.

It doesn't seem you put much research into this question at all, but rather tried randomness and SO.

I'd love to help you, but I can't see the problem. It's not well explained here and it's not shown in the jsfiddle.

Comment: I did put in research.  I do know what I'm doing.  I did not try randomness.  We all mess up now and again.

Comment: @BooBailey I apologize for how that came across -- I wasn't attempting to be rude. Anyway, if your question is still not answered, if you could edit your question and add some information, I'd be glad to assist you.

Comment: It's ok.  This is what I get for working at 10:30pm.  I did figure it out.  The line0height needed to be set to nil.  I feel like an idiot.  And of course, that wouldn't show up when using firebug